# Find the smallest illegal (probable) prime

Tags: code-challenge, primes, compression, encryption

An [illegal prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_prime) is a prime number which encodes information that is illegal to possess - specifically, in one case, a gzip file of the [source code of DeCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDeCSS.PNG), a piece of software to decrypt copy-protected DVDs.

Your task has two phases:

1. Build a source file that implements DeCSS in as few bytes as possible. This can be done in any language.
2. Compress this source file (using your favourite compression algorithm), and iterate through possible files that decompress to the same thing (using [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) if it helps) until primality is reached.

As actually proving primality may take way too much computing power, it will be enough for the second part to pass a "[probable prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime)" test (e.g. [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)) to a probability of less than 2<sup>-100</sup>.

The person with the smallest probable prime wins.

Comment: You may need to use `open("out.gz", 'wb')` instead.

Comment: You said almost exactly what we should do. Where's the fun in just following orders?

Comment: DeCSS is sufficient of a challenge in itself that I [proposed it](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/623/194) in the Sandbox, although no-one seems interested. But it's sufficiently non-trivial to verify that it *needs* a good test suite. As for Dirichlet's theorem: what does that have to do with files which compress to the same thing? How many compression file formats have infinite arithmetic sequences which decompress to the same thing?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: According to the Wikipedia entry (which is where I got that info in the first place), adding trailing null characters to a gzip file will result in the same code being produced upon decompression. Given that you have a valid gzip file, Dirichlet's theorem states that eventually you'll hit upon a prime number by adding null characters to the end of it and then adding a number that's relatively prime to the whole thing.

Comment: @ugoren: It's basically "golf DeCSS", but wrapped up in a secondary challenge.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: As for that test suite, I assume we can't take a few CSS-ed DVD files, run it through both the original DeCSS program and the program to test, and verify that the outputs are the same.

Comment: GNU's implementation might fail to give an error, but if so then it's not a [compliant decompressor](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952#page-9) as defined in the file format spec. As for test cases, they need to be small enough to embed in the question and shouldn't infringe anyone's copyright.

Comment: I think it shouldn't need to follow the spec exactly if, in the spirit of finding an illegal prime, a non-error-producing workaround is needed. I don't know if the original illegal prime is compliant or not.

Comment: @JoeZ. Perhaps it would be prudent to supply a 'fantasy' vendor's key, so that any implementation produced wouldn't actually be, in its exact form.

Comment: Would any random 40-bit number work?

Comment: Is the gzip step actually necessary? I'm getting a larger gzipped file than the raw source.

Comment: The gzip step allows for prime searching, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Java (about 2048 bits)

```
14951059135011030015480908520726485619103063818476057564660360628799292628035097139943806440612109515246411930476451010075357954683100898936593739762786721583164361680031433048702186473094092210118641364347032899100220949873928633438856732508590863996147513646363328498023218161000104939462296626885931085914071985322044175133733909287366858309877885352980365735019082872958155754848273583139151810812417879417661663044291630490856568568829579704849173609110647303708828534149066778229242936297219753177569833591637704406031011600073082097633261877649625598598670707453831253888534424016277678136396605413799234576729
```

The code is

```
void C(int[]s,int[]k){int a=k[0]^s[84]|256,b=k[1]^s[85],c=k[2]^k[3]<<8^k[4]<<16^s[86]^s[87]<<8^s[88]<<16,d=c&7,e=0,f,i=127;for(c=c*2+8-d;++i<2048;e>>=8){e+=S[f=(c>>17^c>>14^c>>13^c>>5)&255]+T[d=Q[b]^R[a]];b=a/2;a=a&1<<8^d;c=c<<8|f;s[i]=P[s[i]]^e&255;}}//!Y
```

I took the liberty of renaming the lookup tables from `CSSt1` ... `CSSt5` to `P` ... `T`, and the method from `CSSDescramble` to `C`. I also ditched the gzip step, because it was giving a larger file than the source.

Comment: Passes Ballie-PSW. Also, am I to understand that your favorite compression algorithm is `None`? ;)

Comment: @primo, my favourite compression algorithm is contextual: the one which gives the smallest result for the input data. ;)